# Run the program in a Linux environment on Windows using Docker

Tags: docker

I need to find out how a simple C console application will work in `Ubuntu`. I have `Windows` installed on my machine. In order not to run the virtual machine, I decided to use `Docker`, it seems to be intended for this purpose. But I don't understand how to do it.

I downloaded and installed `Docker Toolbox` from here https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

Then I run `Docker Quickstart Terminal` and write `$ docker run ubuntu gcc-o hello hello.c` there and get an error:

`C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"gcc\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

`hello.c` - source code in C that prints "hello world" to the screen. This file is located in the same directory as `docker.exe`
Other commands from ubuntu, such as `$ docker run ubuntu echo 'Hello world'` work

[image]

I'm new to Docker. Am I using Docker as intended? If so, why doesn't it work ?

Comment: gcc is not installed.

Comment: @tkausl I have `cygwin` installed on windows. There is a gcc there

Comment: I'd recommend reading some tutorials like Docker's [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial; while that's a Node example, the overall procedure is common across all language.  Generally you compile your program into an _image_ using the `docker build` command, which you can later run.  The plain `ubuntu` image is very minimal and it's only ever really used as a base for other images.

Comment: You're running an ubuntu image which doesn't have gcc installed. The software on your computer doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file and name it `dockerfile` next to your `hello.c`.
Your directory structure should look like this

```
- tempdir
   |_ hello.c
   |_ dockerfile
```

In the `dockerfile` file you will give instructions to docker on how to build your container image. Paste into `dockerfile` theses instructions

```
FROM gcc
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN gcc -o myapp hello.c
CMD ["./myapp"]
```

Then you can build your image using this command

```
C:\tempdir> docker build . --tag helloworldfromgcc 
note: make sure you are in the dockerfile folder
```

and last, run your container :)

```
docker run helloworldfromgcc
```

**Explanations on the dockerfile instructions**

```
# Here you are telling docker that as a base image it should use gcc.
# That image will be downloaded from here: https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc
# that gcc image has the linux kernel and gcc installed on it (not accurate, but good enough to understand)
FROM gcc


# This line will copy your files from your machine disk to the container virtual disk.
# This means the hello.c file will be copied into /usr/src/myapp folder inside the container
COPY . /usr/src/myapp

# This is like doing 'cd /usr/src/myapp'
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

# You know this one :) just call gcc with the standard params
RUN gcc -o myapp hello.c

# CMD differs from run because it will be executed when you run the container, and not when you are building the image
CMD ["./myapp"]
```

Comment: Where should I write the command `C:\tempdir> docker build . --tag helloworldfromgcc` in docker terminal or in cmd.exe? In any case I get an error `unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: CreateFile C:\tempdir\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.` https://ibb.co/jWLxJFw                                            https://ibb.co/gdksCv8

Comment: you have to run all commands in the windows cmd. Do you have the dockerfile and hello.c in C:\tempdir as well? Try using a normal terminal from windows instead of the bash

Comment: It seems to be working. I accidentally created `dockerfile.txt`